# Count files but exclude extention .metadata in the zip file

Tags: linux, bash, unix, zip

I can get the count number of files in the zip but unable to exclude any files have extension metadata.  How can I count only "pdf" files in the zip.  I really appreciate any help you can provide.

```
unzip -l 0532.zip
742248    05-31-2023 15:19   /pdf/0531/CP-1960-5266M.pdf
4125      05-31-2023 15:19   /pdf/0531/CB-CB-177729.pdf.metadata
1221395   05-31-2023 15:19   /pdf/0531/CB-CB-177729.pdf
4128      05-31-2023 15:19   /pdf/0531/CP-1988-10086.pdf.metadata
243050    05-31-2023 15:19   /pdf/0531/CP-1988-10086.pdf
4125      05-31-2023 15:19   /pdf/0531/R-1978448.pdf.metadata
5735942   05-31-2023 15:19   /pdf/0531/R-1978448.pdf
.......   ....              ....
.......   .....             ....
---------                     -------
2152688064                     1634 files
```

I also try this but it fail to exclude "metadata" files. The total count exactly the same.

```
unzip -l 0532.zip | awk '{count = $2} END{print count}'

1634
```

Comment: Are all the files either `.pdf` or `.pdf.metadata`?

Comment: See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a line ends with string `.pdf` increment `counter` by one and after last line output `counter`:

```
unzip -l 0532.zip | awk 'BEGIN{counter=0} /\.pdf$/{counter++} END{print counter}'
```

Output:

```
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Just count the number of lines that end with `.pdf`, using `grep -c`.

```
unzip -l 0532.zip | grep -c '\.pdf$'
```